# Intersection of kernels of all irreducible Brauer characters

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

We now intersection of kernels of all irreducible characters of a group is trivial. Also p-core(G) is contained in kernel of every irreducible Brauer character.

What is the intersection of kernels of all irreducible Brauer characters???

Can we show it is minimal  normal subgroup of group?

Comment: Its a standard result that this intersection is equal to $O_p(G)$ - sorry I don't know a specific reference.

Comment: Thank you very much. If you remember a reference please inform me

Comment: Search for "p-parts of brauer character degrees navarro". It's Lemma 3.2 in that paper.

Comment: Thank you very much Prof. Holt

Answer (score 2):

Here is a brief argument:  since the Brauer table, as a matrix, has full rank, every $p’$ element has a nontrivial image under some irreducible representation. That means that the intersection of all kernels can only contain $p$ elements, and thus can’t be larger than $O_p$.

Comment: Tank you for the proof.